# Can a MongoDB assign a separate memory for the applicaiton?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In case of I don't want the user queries impact to the application performance,
Is there any way to manage memory or allocate memory for the application separate from the user queries?

Thank you

Comment: Your application is different from your database. The query submitted by the application runs on the database server. I suggest you include some more details about the application and data in your post,

Comment: Dear @prasad_ 
Sorry, I'm not sure about the application. 
The application teams just ask me about can MongoDB allocate more memory specific for the application services that usually get data from MongoDB.
May I change the question, can I manage memory specification for each username?

Comment: As I said before, application is different from MongoDB server. If the application submits more queries, and access more data, then it can be concluded as the database server uses more memory - to process the more data.

Answer (score 1):

Add another node to your replica set. Make it a hidden node. Run user queries on that node.

Comment: Dear @D. SM I'm a newbie in MongoDB Is the hidden node able to read/write normally?

Comment: That is a sloppily formulated question. Yes, the node can read and write its own disk normally.

Comment: Dear @D. SM Thank you for your answer.
can I ask more some questions? for the hidden node, can I set the primary to run the high priority activity and write the audit log to the hidden node instead??

Comment: You can ask that as its own question.